# Retrieve UISegmentedControl object out of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to get the `UISegmentedControl` object that i previously added in the `UIBarButtonItem` like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmaentControl];
```

now i want to get the `UISegmentedControl` object out of it, how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`UIBarButtonItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a property called [`customView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW12), which is what you're looking for:

```
UISegmentedControl *control = (UISegmentedControl *) [segmentBarButton customView];
```

Comment: thanks 4 your help. usually it happens that u forget the basic thing.